# azure function with parameters from logic app

Tags: azure-functions

Can someone tell me how I can receive parameters in my Azure function?

I have a Logic app that is triggered by a sql new entry.  I want that to trigger an azure function with items from that sql new entry.

I already have the logic app triggered by sql, and I already have those parameters ready in the logic app.  And I know how to launch the function from the logic app. I just don't know how to have the azure function receive those parameters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to call a function from a logic app and want to pass some data, you can compose parameters as json object and pass that object to function call.

[Function call screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KccG8.png)

In the function you can read it using stream reader and deserialize as shown in the code below.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
    {
        CustomerDataRequest data = null;
          
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The request body is null or empty");
            }

            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerDataRequest>(requestBody);
}

 public class CustomerDataRequest
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```